# Suddenly unable to install package 'mfx'

Tags: installation, package

I have been blithely using R for some time when suddenly I'm having trouble installing packages, specifically mfx. It appears to be downloading. But then when I input library(mfx), I get this: Loading required package: sandwich
Loading required package: lmtest
Loading required package: zoo

Attaching package: ‘zoo’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

```
as.Date, as.Date.numeric
```

Loading required package: MASS
Loading required package: betareg
Error in get(".packageName", where) : 
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Mary Graybeal/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/modeltools/R/modeltools.rdb': No such file or directory
Error: package ‘betareg’ could not be loaded

As part of my efforts to resolve it, I uninstalled and reinstalled; no help there. I use RStudio, but the same thing happens in R, and so the problem is not RStudio. Am I overlooking something really obvious here?

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-install the previous package, in this case MODELTOOLS

**install.packages("modeltools")**

Loading required package: MASS Loading required package: betareg Error in get(".packageName", where) : cannot open file 'C:/Users/Mary Graybeal/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/**modeltools**/R/modeltools.rdb': No such file or directory Error: package ‘betareg’ could not be loaded

Maybe an another errors appear, you have to do the same step with each package.